# Checking if getattr exists within a dictionary comprehension in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension, getattr

I have a line of code

```
attributes_dict["data_properties"] = {
    prop: getattr(ontology_node, prop) for prop in data_properties
}
```

However, not every ontology_node will have all of the properties, so I'd like to do something similar to the following

```
attributes_dict["data_properties"] = {
    prop: getattr(ontology_node, prop) for prop in data_properties if getattr(onotology_node, prop)
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work properly. Is there a way to check if that exists within the ontology_node within a dict comprehension like the above?

Of course I can manually do this, but I would like to use a dict comprehension if possible.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work properly"?

Comment: Use `.__dict__` to check if key you are looking for is in the dictionary.

Comment: It throws an error saying that the property is not in the ontology node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) should do the work

```
attributes_dict["data_properties"] = {
    prop: getattr(ontology_node, prop) for prop in data_properties if hasattr(onotology_node, prop)
}
```

PS: `prop` should be of a `str` type

Comment: For your editification it's also possible to give `getattr` a third value, which is a *default*, returned in case the attribute is not present on the object. This doesn't seem too useful here unless you use an assignment hack but in other situations it is quite convenient.